# Searching with 'All' Keyword in the Fulltext search results in listing all results instead of results having word 'All'

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am using Search API Database search in my site.
I created search page using views and added fulltext search in the filters.
When I tried to search for 'All' Keyword in the FullText search, instead of pulling the nodes having 'All' in the content of the nodes it is listing all the nodes .
But the same is not happening when I search with keyword 'all'.

Did anyone face similar issues in your sites?
If yes, can you please let me know the solution for this problem?

Thanks,
Krishna.